# How to close popup in Django Admin

Tags: django, django-forms, django-admin, python-3.7

I am using Python 3.7.10 with Django 3.1.6, and I have used the following code to create an admin popup that will be triggered when clicking on the "**edit_link**":

```
class EditLinkWidget(forms.URLInput):
    def render(self, name, value, attrs, renderer):
        super().render(name, value, attrs, renderer)
        if not value:
            return ''

        return mark_safe(f'<a class="related-widget-wrapper-link change-related" href="{value}?_to_field=id&_popup=1" '\
                         'data-href-template="{}?_to_field=id&_popup=1">Edit</a>').format(
            re.sub("(\d+)", "__fk__", value))


class PageForm(TranslatableModelForm):
    edit_link = forms.CharField(widget=EditLinkWidget, required=False, disabled=True)

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        if self.instance.pk:
            self.fields['edit_link'].initial = f'/admin/cms/car/{self.instance.car_id}/change/')
    class Meta:
        model = User
        fields = ('edit_link',)
```

It works great, but the problem is that the popup doesn't close automatically when I click on the **Save** button, throwing the following javascript error:

[image]

Does somebody know how can I fix it so the popup can be closed automatically? I guess it should communicate with the parent admin page somehow?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seems like I just missed adding a unique id to each popup. After adding `id="{name}"` it all works as expected. The final code looks like this:

```
class EditLinkWidget(forms.URLInput):
    def render(self, name, value, attrs, renderer):
        super().render(name, value, attrs, renderer)
        if not value:
            return ''

        return mark_safe(f'<a id="{name}" class="related-widget-wrapper-link change-related" href="{value}?_to_field=id&_popup=1" '\
                         'data-href-template="{}?_to_field=id&_popup=1">Edit</a>').format(
            re.sub("(\d+)", "__fk__", value))


class PageForm(TranslatableModelForm):
    edit_link = forms.CharField(widget=EditLinkWidget, required=False, disabled=True)

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        if self.instance.pk:
            self.fields['edit_link'].initial = f'/admin/cms/car/{self.instance.car_id}/change/')
    class Meta:
        model = User
        fields = ('edit_link',)
```

Answer (score 0):

This is a problem from your front-end.
I assume your pop up is a BS modal, be sure you have done everything well. Modals should close without springing up errors.